# Spring-Boot how to disable "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

I have a problem with tomcat included with spring boot. i want to disable the chunked encoding or even using the HTTP 1.0 version as it doesn't use it. i don't have a java class for that i just want to change the properties.

below the part of the HTTP response header that i received with the chunked encoding

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Date: Thu, 26 Sep 2019 15:46:57 GMT
Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Why? Any non-ancient HTTP client should support chunked encoding. What did the request look like? Did it specify HTTP 1.0? Did it ask for the connection to stay alive?